# A better way to import HTML elements?

Tags: javascript, html, import

I'm trying to import elements from another HTML in this way, and it works, but although in localhost looks good, in github pages looks horrible and it give me some bugs and limitations

¿What another option do I have to import HTML elements and don't repeat code?

**header.html**

```
<div class="logo-container" id="container">
        <a href="index.html">
            <img src="assets/img/logo.jpg" alt="Bright Academy">
        </a>
</div>

<div class="menu" id="menu">
            <img src="../../assets/icons/burger-menu.svg" alt="">
</div>
```

**index.js**

```
function importElements() {
    const header = document.getElementById('header');
    const footer = document.getElementById('footer');
    const sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar');
    function chargeHTMLElements(url, parent) {
        fetch(url)
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(element => {
                parent.innerHTML = element;
            })
    }

chargeHTMLElements('/src/layouts/header.html', header);
chargeHTMLElements('/src/layouts/footer.html', footer);
chargeHTMLElements('/src/layouts/sidebar.html', sidebar);  
}

importElements();
```

**index.html**

```
<!--Header charged since import.js-->
<header class="header" id="header" ></header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider waiting to display the whole page only once all responses are come back, so the whole content appears at once. Start out with something like

```
<body class="loading">
```

```
.loading {
  display: none; // or make a more fancy looking loading screen
}
```

so that nothing gets displayed initially. Then use `Promise.all` to wait for all responses, and once all are back, remove the class from the body to show everything:

```
function chargeHTMLElements(url, parent) {
    return fetch(url) // make sure to return this Promise
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(element => {
            parent.innerHTML = element;
        })
}
Promise.all([
    chargeHTMLElements('/src/layouts/header.html', header),
    chargeHTMLElements('/src/layouts/footer.html', footer),
    chargeHTMLElements('/src/layouts/sidebar.html', sidebar),
])
    .then(() => {
        document.body.classList.remove('loading');
    })
    .catch(handleErrors); // don't forget this part
```

An even better solution would be to use a template engine like EJS so that the *server* servers the HTML to the client with the header, footer, and sidebar already populated, instead of having the client separately fetch and populate the DOM.

Comment: Thank you! I tried the solution but github pages doesn't work well still. Anyway, it may be a different trouble,because neither charge some CSS that are imported since a index.css

Anyway in localhost works well and I'l try to use a template engine =)

Comment: What exactly do you mean, "doesn't work well"? Make sure to tweak the CSS so that nothing is displayed on the page before the responses from the server all come back

Comment: https://nazarenoalt.github.io/bright-academy you can see the content is broken, but that doesn't happen in a local server.,only in github pages (I pushed the changes in the repository)

Comment: None of the pages you're requesting exist at the endpoints. Eg `https://nazarenoalt.github.io/src/layouts/header.html` doesn't exist at all. Right now, this isn't a CSS or layout issue, but an issue of you just not having pushed the required files your site needs

Comment: Omg, that's weird. The repository has the files pushed in here https://github.com/nazarenoalt/bright-academy/tree/main/src/layouts

Comment: The URL you're using is wrong. You need `https://nazarenoalt.github.io/bright-academy/src/layouts/header.html`, not `https://nazarenoalt.github.io/src/layouts/header.html`

Comment: I got it. How can I fix the URL direction?

Comment: By adding in the missing `bright-academy` to the start